# Closed Set - Closed Set = $F_{\sigma}$ set?

Tags: borel-sets

Let $A$ and $B$ be closed sets in $\mathbb{R}$. Is $A\setminus B$ an $F_{\sigma}$ set?

Comment: Please iinclude your own thoughts and ideas , Also add more information as the question is too vague in its current state. See here on [how to ask a good question](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: It is both an $F_\sigma$ set and a $G_\delta$ set.

Answer (score 0):

The set difference $A-B$ is the same as $A \cap B'$ where $B'$ means the complement of $B$ and so is open. So show that an open set is also an $F_\sigma$ set, which is to say a countable union of closed sets. To do this, use that an open set is a countable union of pairwise disjoint open intervals, and each of those is the union of a countable increasing family of closed intervals.

Comment: What about this? 
Let A and B be F_{\sigma} sets in ℝ. Is A∖B an F_{\sigma} set?